# Is Microsoft Visual Studio improperly defining the values of Type Traits?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

As part of some Geometric functions I'm implementing for a project, I figured it would be a good idea to help constrain the types that could be fed into the library to only Geometric Types. So I wrote the following struct to aid with that:

```
template<typename T>
struct Geometric {
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "T Must be Arithmetic!");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, std::decay_t<T>>, "Must be raw type!");
};

//...

template<typename T>
struct point2 : Geometic<T> {
    //...
};
```

Then, because my library needs to make use of a custom type that obeys all the common conventions of arithmetic types (at least as far as this project is concerned) I figured an easy solution to integrate this type into the library was to simply add an entry for `std::is_arithmetic` for that type:

```
using rational_t = boost::multiprecision::cpp_rational;

template<>
struct std::is_arithmetic<rational_t> : std::true_type {};

using rational_point = point2<rational_t>;
```

However, this code consistently produced the "T must be arithmetic!" error message at compile-time. So I did a little digging into Microsoft's implementation of these type traits and found something that I wasn't expecting: the derivation of `std::is_arithmetic_v<T>` comes directly from other constants, *not* from its associated struct.

```
//MSVC2019 Code found in 'xtr1common', line# 197
// STRUCT TEMPLATE is_arithmetic
template <class _Ty>
_INLINE_VAR constexpr bool is_arithmetic_v = // determine whether _Ty is an arithmetic type
    is_integral_v<_Ty> || is_floating_point_v<_Ty>;

template <class _Ty>
struct is_arithmetic : bool_constant<is_arithmetic_v<_Ty>> {};
```

This, of course, stymied my code, because my specialization of `is_arithmetic<rational_t>` was having absolutely no effect on the definition of `is_arithmetic_v<rational_t>`.

It specifically stymied me because I was expecting the specialization to work in reverse, deriving `is_arithmetic_v` from `is_arithmetic`, as it's detailed on [CPPReference's page for this type trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic):

> #### Helper variable template
>
> ```
> template< class T >
> inline constexpr bool is_arithmetic_v = is_arithmetic<T>::value;
> ```

> #### Possible implementation
>
> ```
> template< class T >
> struct is_arithmetic : std::integral_constant<bool,
>                                               std::is_integral<T>::value ||
>                                               std::is_floating_point<T>::value> {};
> ```

So is MSVC's definition of this trait (and many other traits, which seem to follow similar patterns) legal according to the standard, or is this a mistake in the implementation? If I need to specialize these kinds of constants in the future, what's the ideomatic way to do so?

Comment: This is tricky, on the one hand, you should be able to specialize the template since there is not explicit requirement that you cant.  On the other hand [`T` is required to be an arithmetic type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta.unary.comp#tab:meta.unary.comp), so no specialization should be valid.  Not sure what wins in this case.

Comment: @NathanOliver Cppreference [claims](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Adding_template_specializations) one is not allowed to specialize templates from `<type_traits>` (except `common_type`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat They are right

Comment: I'm just going to add that sentence to every single trait's page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specializing templates from `<type_traits>` (other than `std::common_type`) appears to not be allowed:

> [**cppreference:**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Adding_template_specializations)
>
> None of the templates defined in `<type_traits>` may be specialized for a program-defined type, except for `std::common_type`.

The revelant part of the standard is: (courtesy of @NathanOliver)

> [**[meta.rqmts]/4**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta#rqmts-4):
>
> Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the templates specified in this subclause [meta] is undefined.

So the implementation used by MSVC is conforming.

The classical workaround is to make your own trait (based on the standard one) and specialize it instead.

```
template <typename T>
struct IsArithmetic : std::is_arithmetic<T> {};
```